# Why do I have to wait before I can trade my Steam Awards Foil card?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I managed to pick up a foil card during the Steam Awards.  I'm not going to try to craft the badge for the foils so I want to get rid of it as soon as possible (while prices are still relatively high).  But for whatever reason, it says I cannot trade/sell it til after a certain date (2017-01-03).

[image]

Yet, it seems the market has been open for a while now and people are already selling the thing.

http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/753/566020-Game%20Within%20a%20Game%20%28Foil%20Trading%20Card%29

Why am I not allowed to sell this thing *now*?

I haven't changed anything recently as far as I'm aware.  I had to reconfirm my Paypal information again while buying stuff but that's it.  I'm still able to trade the regular cards (as well as any other card for other games).  What makes *this* foil card so special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This card is not tradable, because you received it while crafting a badge. Trading cards received by going through your discovery queue, or by buying a game, do not receive such a restriction.

As to why this restriction is in place is anyone's guess.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Official or otherwise community driven? I was pretty sure that I was able to trade other cards I gained through crafting almost immediately after receiving them.

Comment: Source is my own experience. Trade restrictions on items is not uncommon on Steam though. Unboxing items in, for example, CS:GO, will put a trade restriction of a week on that specific item. All the "The Steam Awards" trading cards that I received through crafting have, or had, a trade restriction on it.

Comment: Ok, I'll take your word for it. I guess those that have sold the cards on day one of the awards must have been lucky and gotten the cards randomly.

Comment: There's a lot of discussion on Steam's forums of people not being able to trade/sell cards from crafting.  [1](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/458604254442019553/) [2](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/7/598198356172834855/) [3](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/598199244892653667/). Including the topic of crafting was what I needed to add in my searches.

Comment: Presumably because the relative price of foil cards to common cards is low enough that you could grind out badges to get foil cards and make free money.

Comment: @SGR No. Any "Steam Awards" trading card received from crafting badges is not tradable for a while.